# Content disappears after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my react app. I have a blog page where I can create blog posts and display them to the screen. In this part everything works fine. User logs in and can write a post. Each post contains a Read more... link and if the user clicks on that link the app redirects to the actual blog post. There the user can read the whole blog and add some comments. Everything works perfectly except when the user refreshes the page, everything disappears without any error in the console. I use firebase as my back-end and everything is saved there just like it has to be. Each time I click on the particular post I get redirected to that post and everything is ok, but when I refresh the page everything disappears, the post, the comments, even the input field and the submit comment button.

Here is a picture before refresh:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRm2q.png)

here is a picture after refresh:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC9pr.png)

Also I will include the code for the actual blog and comment section.
The BlogAndCommentPage contains the actual blog post and holds the input field for the comments and the comments that belong to this post.

```
import React from 'react'
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';
import BackToBlogs from './BackToBlogs'
import AddComment from '../commentComponents/AddComment'

class BlogAndCommentPage extends React.Component {
    state = { param: '', blog: [] }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
        const id = urlParams.get('id')
        this.setState({ param: id })

        const fetchDataFromFireBase = async () => {
            projectFirestore.collection('Blogs').doc(id).get()
                .then(doc => {
                    if(doc.exists) {
                        let document = [];
                        document.push(doc.data());
                        this.setState({ blog: document })
                    }
                })
        }

        fetchDataFromFireBase()
    }
    
    renderContent() {
        // Display the blog
        const blogs = this.state.blog?.map(value => {
            return (
                <div key={value.post.blogID}>
                    <h1>{value.post.title}</h1>
                    <h6>{`${value.post.name} - ${value.post.date}`}</h6>
                    <p>{value.post.body}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return blogs;
    }

    render() {
        const displayedBlog = this.state.param
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    displayedBlog ? (
                        <div>
                        {this.renderContent()}
                        <BackToBlogs />
                        <hr></hr>
                        <h5 className="mb-2">Add a comment</h5>
                        <AddComment param={this.state.param} />
                        </div>
                    ) : ''
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default BlogAndCommentPage
```

The AddComment component holds the submit button for the comments and the list of the components

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import SubmitComment from './SubmitComment'
import CommentHolder from './CommentHolder';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const AddComment = ({ param }) => {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            alert('You are not logged in. Click OK to log in.')
            window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/'
        }
    }, [])

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const state = useSelector((state) => state.state);

    if (state) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setComment('')
            dispatch({ type: "SET_FALSE" })
        }, 50)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Comment" className="form-control mb-3" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <SubmitComment comment={comment} param={param} />
            </div>
            <CommentHolder param={param} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddComment
```

The CommentHolder renders each comment that belong to that post

```
import React from 'react';
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';
import DeleteComment from './DeleteComment'

class CommentHolder extends React.Component {

    state = { docs: [] }
    _isMounted = false;

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const fetchDataFromFireBase = async () => {
            const getData = await projectFirestore.collection("Comments")
            getData.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                var documents = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                });
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ docs: documents })
                }
            });
        }
        fetchDataFromFireBase()
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    renderContent() {

        // Delete comments
        const deleteComment = async (id) => {
            projectFirestore.collection('Comments').doc(String(id)).delete().then(() => {
                console.log(`Blog with id: ${id} has been successfully deleted!`)
            })
        }

        // Build comments
        let user;
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            user = [];
        } else {
            user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));

            const commentArray = this.state.docs?.filter(value => value.blogID === this.props.param)
                .sort((a, b) => (a.time > b.time) ? -1 : (b.time > a.time) ? 1 : 0)
                    .map(comment => {
                return (
                    <div key={comment.id} className="card mb-3" >
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm">
                                    <h6>{`${comment.name} - ${comment.time}`}</h6>
                                    <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm text-right">
                                    {user[0].id === comment.userID ? <DeleteComment commentid={comment.id} onDeleteComment={deleteComment} /> : ''}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            });

            const updateComments = () => {
                const queryString = window.location.search;
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
                const id = urlParams.get('id')

                const updateComment = projectFirestore.collection('Blogs').doc(id);
                return updateComment.update({
                    'post.comments': commentArray.length
                })
            }
            updateComments()
            return commentArray;

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentHolder
```

The DeleteComment deletes the comment

```
import React from 'react'

const DeleteComment = ({ commentid, onDeleteComment }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onDeleteComment(commentid)} className='btn btn-outline-danger'>X</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DeleteComment
```

The SubmitComment stores the comment in the Firebase

```
import React from 'react'
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const SubmitComment = ({ comment, param }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onCommentSubmit = () => {
        let user;
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            user = [];
        } else {
            user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
            projectFirestore.collection('Comments').doc().set({
                id: uuidv4(),
                comment,
                name: `${user[0].firstName} ${user[0].lastName}`,
                userID: user[0].id,
                blogID: param,
                time: new Date().toLocaleString()
            })

            dispatch({ type: "SET_TRUE" });
        }
    }

    

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onCommentSubmit()} className='btn btn-primary'>Add comment</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SubmitComment
```

In case there is a rout problem here is the code for the routing between the blogs section and the blog + comments section

```
    return (
        <Router >
            <Route path='/content-page' exact render={(props) => (
                <>
                    <BlogAndCommentPage />
                </>
            )} />
            <Route path='/blogpage' exact render={(props) => (
                <>
                    <div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-8">
                                <h1 className='mb-3'>Blog</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-4 mb-3">
                                <LogoutButton onLogOut={logout} />
                                <h6 className='float-right mt-4 mr-2'>{displayUser}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {empty ? (<div style={{ color: "red", backgroundColor: "#F39189", borderColor: "red", borderStyle: "solid", borderRadius: "5px", textAlign: 'center' }} className="mb-2">Title and body cannot be blank</div>
                        ) : ("")}
                        <InputArea getBlogContent={getBlogContent} />
                        <CreateBlog post={post} onCheckEmptyInputs={checkEmptyTitleAndBody} />
                        <hr />
                        <BlogHolder />
                    </div>
                </>
            )} />

        </Router>

    )
```

If anybody has any clue on why is this happening, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As your website is CSR (client side rendering) it doesn't understand the URL in the first execution, you might need to configure a hash router, take a look at:

> https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Also, there is a good answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/15611356)